# htaccess / mod_rewrite commands for creating a hardcoded permalink

Tags: .htaccess

I want to create a permalink and I don't want users to see the actual url or subfolder names.

i have the following in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^shortcut/(.*)$ /some/sub/folder/$1 [PT,L]
```

It has several issues.

1. `example.com/shortcut`

Throws a 404 error

2. `example.com/shortcut/`   <-- trailing slash

This loads the correct page, with images, <s>but all the relative hyper links on the page are linking to the parent. i.e. `example.com/faq` instead of `example.com/shortcut/faq`</s> (this was actually an issue on the page, using `href="/faq/"` instead of `href="faq/"`

---

**update (still not there)**

```
RewriteRule ^shortcut$ some/sub/folder [PT]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shortcut/(.*)$ some/sub/folder/$1 [L,PT]
```

After some more googling I came up with the above, which works, but it changes the URL in the title bar of the browser, which I'm trying to avoid.

---

**update 2 (kinda there)**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^shortcut$ /shortcut/ [L,R]
RewriteRule ^shortcut/(.*)$  some/sub/folder/$1 [L,PT]
```

This seems to work for the pages I've tested
Final remaining question... is this the best/safest/most performant solution?